# XHTML STRICT 1.0 TABLE

Tags: html, xhtml, html-table

I have a table without using css. I do not want the css.
Table 3 columns and 3 rows, with cell fusion in rows and columns (colspan and rowspan attributes) 
I do not find a way to get 3 columns at the end of the same width (200 px) without using CSS

Thanks

```
<table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
     <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td colspan="2">b</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">c</td>
        <td>d</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>e</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>w1</td>
        <td>w2</td>
        <td>w3</td>

     </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vfwsLmbm. I this not you're expecting?

Comment: Thanks. No because w1 and w2 have width 199px. And I want w1 w2 w3  = 200px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`col` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4.2) to specify column widths. This is valid in XHTML 1.0 Strict, even though setting widths on cells is not. Assuming you want a width of 200 pixels for each column (cf. to @AlexThomas’s answer), you can use this:

```html
<table width="603" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
<col width="200"/>
<col width="200"/>
<col width="200"/>
     <tr>
        <td>I have put some extra text here to illustrate that
            this cell is not expanded past the 200px limit.</td>
        <td colspan="2">b</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">c</td>
        <td>d</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>e</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>w1</td>
        <td>w2</td>
        <td>w3</td>

     </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> user3279494: Thanks. No because w1 and w2 have width 199px. And I want w1 w2 w3 =
>   200px

It's because you have 1px border, it's including that. Take off the border, your rows are 200px. So if you want the columns to be 200px, with the border, you'll need to increase the table size to 603px

```
<table width="603" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
     <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td colspan="2">b</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">c</td>
        <td>d</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>e</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>w1</td>
        <td>w2</td>
        <td>w3</td>

     </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: This is not sufficient if the cells have more content so that browsers allocate widths according to content requirements.

Comment: It's not possible without change my table width?